# Which data structure to choose for scenario A and B as described below

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I found the below in a question bank and I'm looking for some help with it.

> For each of the following situations, select the best data structure and justify your selection.
>   The data structures should be selected from the following possibilities: unordered list, ordered array, heap, hash table, binary search tree.
>
> (a) (4 points) Your structure needs to store a potentially very large number of records, with the data being added as it arrives. You need to be able to retrieve a record by its primary key, and these keys are random with respect to the order in which the data arrives. Records also may be deleted at random times, and all modifications to the data need to be completed just after they are submitted by the users. You have no idea how large the dataset could be, but the data structure implementation needs to be ready in a few weeks. While you are designing the program, the actual programming is going to be done by a co-op student.

For the answer, I thought BST would be the best choice.

Since the size is not clear, hashtable is not a good choice.
Since there is a matter of deletion, heap is not acceptable either.

Is my reasoning correct?

> (b) (4 points) You are managing data for the inventory of a large warehouse store. New items (with new product keys) are added and deleted from the inventory system every week, but this is done while stores are closed for 12 consecutive hours.
>
> Quantities of items are changed frequently: incremented as they are stocked, and decremented as they are sold. Stocking and selling items requires the item to be retrieved from the system using its product key.
>
> It is also important that the system be robust, well-tested, and have predictable behaviour. Delays in retrieving an item are not acceptable, since it could cause problems for the sales staff. The system will potentially be used for a long time, though largely it is only the front end that is likely to be modified.

For this part I thought heapsort, but I have no idea how to justify my answer.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) needs fast insertion and deletion and you need retrieval based on key. Thus I'd go with a hashtable or a binary search tree. However, since the size is not known in advance and there's that deadline constraint, I'd say the binary search tree is the best alternative.

(b) You have enough time to process data after insertion/deletion but need an O(1) random access. An ordered array should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, for b) why do n't you use hashtable?

Comment: You need to compute a hash and then to handle collisions. The problem is with collisions-> it might blow the access time.

Comment: For b) you only get O(1) random access if all product keys are consecutive(not just ordered). Otherwise you have to binary search the index from the product key. Still a good O(logn) solution, though.

Comment: Still I am a little confused: it sais this system gonna work for long so the size is unclear how can we use ordered list when size is unclear?